# how to get receiver phone number from sms application?

Tags: android

I have a problem in finding out the receiver phone number from the incoming SMS. Here is the code that I am trying:

i have find the sender number form receiver side.but i don't know receiver number [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451132/android-how-to-get-sender-and-receiver-phone-number-from-raw-sms?rq=1)

Can someone tell me how to retrieve receiver phone number from sms.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
```

Comment: You mean, you want to get the device's own number?

Comment: i tried this method of coding find my device mobile number.

Comment: TelephonyManager telephoneManager =(TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String mPhoneNumber1 = telephoneManager.getLine1Number();

Comment: but it's not working for me.. how to resolve this problem. please guide me. thanks

Comment: Well, it's not going to be in the SMS table. The best you can get from that is the SIM slot a message was received on.